# AsyncTask - onPostExecute UI confuse

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I tried to figure out whats going wrong myself via search but I missed something else, I think.

I have a class with doInBackground which checking something for me, and return TRUE or FALSE to onPostExecute. With debug, I found out code is working, param sends through the functions and line-by-line is working but UI is not updating where they must.

Here is part of my code:

```
class check extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //some code here

        if(tmp.equals(SSID)){
            return true;
        } else {           
            //little bit of code
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean is) {
       super.onPostExecute(is);
        if(is){
            Button State = (Button) findViewById(R.id.State);
            State.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_ringcnt);
        } else {
            Button State = (Button) findViewById(R.id.State);
            State.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_ringnrdy);
        }
    }
}
```

I think code I hided is doing nothing with UI of course, but if everything else is all right i can show hidden part.

Comment: are you sure its is running the code onPostExecute

Comment: if so i think you need to refresh the view

Comment: write State.invalidate() after setbackground

Comment: @has19 thanks! I tried it, but still UI is not updating. I alsho checked the code and Iam pretty sure code is running right in OnPostExecute

Comment: just set new layoutparam to the button as they were from xml after State.setBackgroundResource and i think it should work .this way the view should be refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed Button with ImageView and thats it! I dont know why it doesnt work with Button, but with ImageView and changing URI of resor